# shortcut for filling missing dates

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, missing-data

I have the following example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

idx1 = pd.period_range('2015-01-01', freq='10T', periods=1000)

idx2 = pd.period_range('2016-01-01', freq='10T', periods=1000)

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000), index=idx1, 
                   columns=['A'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000), index=idx2, 
                   columns=['A'])

frames = [df1, df2]

df_concat = pd.concat(frames)
```

Now, I would like to know the number of missing dates in df_concat

So I filled the dates and reindexed the data frame:

```
start_total = df1.index[0]
end_total = df2.index[-1]
idx_total = pd.period_range(start=start_total, end=end_total, freq='10T')
df_total = df_concat.reindex(idx_total, fill_value=np.nan)
df_miss = df_total[df_total.isnull()]
```

Is there a shorter version for the last code segments?

Something like `df_concat.fill_missing_dates`?
This was provided with the timeseries scikit:
[scikits.timeseries.TimeSeries.fill_missing_dates](http://pytseries.sourceforge.net/generated/scikits.timeseries.TimeSeries.fill_missing_dates.html?highlight=fill#scikits.timeseries.TimeSeries.fill_missing_dates)

Comment: Maybe help `print df_concat.resample('10T')`

Comment: `df.fill_missing_dates(fill_value=...)` is equivalent to `df.fillna(value=...)` (if the NaNs are already there and you do not change the frequence), or to `df.resample(freq).fillna(value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
df_total = df_concat.resample('10T')
print df_total[df_total.isnull()] 

                     A
2015-01-01 00:00:00 NaN
2015-01-01 00:10:00 NaN
2015-01-01 00:20:00 NaN
2015-01-01 00:30:00 NaN
2015-01-01 00:40:00 NaN
2015-01-01 00:50:00 NaN
2015-01-01 01:00:00 NaN
2015-01-01 01:10:00 NaN
2015-01-01 01:20:00 NaN
2015-01-01 01:30:00 NaN
2015-01-01 01:40:00 NaN
2015-01-01 01:50:00 NaN
2015-01-01 02:00:00 NaN
2015-01-01 02:10:00 NaN
2015-01-01 02:20:00 NaN
```